# How are the "Link Strength true", "Link Strength blind" and "Mutual Information" calculated in this report on Bayesian networks?

Tags: papers, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the strength of every arc in a Bayesian Network.

I came across this report [Measuring Connection Strengths and Link Strengths in Discrete Bayesian Networks](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/14331/GT-IIC-07-01.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), but I got lost in the calculation.

In particular, how are the values of Link Strength true, Link Strength blind, and Mutual Information computed in Table 1?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The $MI$ is easy enough.
For $MI(X \to Z)$, we get $U([0.5, 0.5]) - 0.5 U([0.9, 0.1]) - 0.5 U([0.1, 0.9])$. The $[0.5, 0.5]$ comes from $0.5 [0.9, 0.1] + 0.5[0.1, 0.9]$ -- this is how to calculate $P(Z)$ from $P(Z|X)$ and $P(X)$.
For $MI(X \to Y)$, we need to marginalize out $Z$. This takes a bit of work, but is not too hard. I manually verified all of the reported values in the figure, and they are all correct.

The $\mathrm{LS}{\mathrm{true}}$ values are a bit trickier, but still feasible. I managed to get the same values. It is important when calculating $\mathrm{LS}{\mathrm{true}}(X \to Z)$ that $Y$ is not a parent, so it does not come into it -- which is why the MI gives exactly the same value.

The "blind" version took me a bit more effort to implement, but again, I am getting the same values as reported in the table.
I used the "simple formula" at the top of page 5.

Comment: Thank you very much @Robby, it helps me understand some part. I don't have a strong mathematical background, which makes me struggle to translate the formulas and numbers in the paper. I'm doing a python code for this formula, and still figure out which variables need to hold which numbers. So please apologize.

When you mentioned $MI(X \to Z)$ = $U([0.5,0.5])−0.5U([0.9,0.1])−0.5U([0.1,0.9])$, it does use formula (2) $U(Z)-U(Z|X)$, right? 
There is also a formula 
$\sum\limits_{x,y}P(x,y) log_{2} (\frac{P(x,y)}{P(x)P(y)})$, and I'm not sure how to derive numbers for $P(x,y), P(x), P(y)$.

Comment: Yes, I used formula (2) for that.

$P(x,y) = P(y | x) \cdot P(x)$. You might want to take an introduction to probability theory, make sure it covers things up to conditional probabilities, entropy and Bayes' theorem; you'll encounter those a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Robby,

I will look at those materials asap. I have quickly tried to find the numbers for: $P(z,x)=0.5; P(x)=0,5; P(z)=0.5$. 

I got it from $P(z,x)$ = the average of $P(z|x=true)$ and $P(z|x=false)$, which yield 0.5. $P(x) = P(x=true) = 0.5$. $P(z=true)$ = the average of 0.9 and 0.1 = 0.5. But the result is different from the table when I plug in those number in the formula. 

I believe I calculated those wrongly, but it will help me to also understand the materials that you suggested if I know where my mistakes are. Thanks again Robby and I will update my understanding.

Comment: If $P(z|x) = 0.5$ and $P(x) = 0.5$, then $P(x, z) = 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 0.25$.

Comment: The calculation you did ($P(z=\mathrm{True}|x=\mathrm{True}) P(x=\mathrm{True}) + P(z =\mathrm{True}| x=\mathrm{False})$ gives us $P(z=\mathrm{True})$, not $P(z, x)$.

Comment: Hey @Robby, 

I have done the calculation for $(X \to Y)$ and $(Z \to Y)$.

$(X \to Y) = U([0.4982, 0.5017]) - 0.5([0.41, 0.09]) - 0.5([0.094, 0.406])$ = 0.1556174 
$(Z \to Y) = U([0.4982, 0.5017]) - 0.5([0.4495, 0.0505]) - 0.5([0.0545, 0.4455])$ = 0.2576914

As you see, my results are half of the correct results and I'm wondering which my mistakes are.

Some details of my calculations are:
$U(Y)= 0.9999538$ 
$U(Y|X)= 0.844336$ 
$U(Y|Z)= 0.7422624$

Comment: The Joint distribution:
$P(Y=t | X=t,Z=t) * P(Z=t | X=t) * P(X=t) =0.405$
$P(Y=t | X=f,Z=t) * P(Z=t | X=f) * P(X=f) =0.0445$
$P(Y=t | X=t,Z=f) * P(Z=f | X=t) * P(X=t) =0.005$
$P(Y=t | X=f,Z=f) * P(Z=f | X=f) * P(X=f) =0.0495$
$P(Y=f | X=t,Z=t) * P(Z=t | X=t) * P(X=t) =0.045$
$P(Y=f | X=f,Z=t) * P(Z=t | X=f) * P(X=f) =0.0055$
$P(Y=f | X=t,Z=f) * P(Z=f | X=t) * P(X=t) =0.045$
$P(Y=f | X=f,Z=f) * P(Z=f | X=f) * P(X=f) =0.4005$

The Marginal:
$P(Z=t) = 0.5$ and $P(Z=f) = 0.5$
$P(Y=t) = 0.504$ and $P(Y=f) = 0.496$

I'm sorry I cannot present the comment with a clear formating. Thanks

Comment: Your joint and marginal distributions are correct. U(Y) is correct as well. For U(Y|X), that is equal to U(X, Y) - U(X), which gives me 0.68867. I think that's where your calculations are off.

Comment: Thanks @Robby,

I calculated $U(X,Y)$, but, it seems even off from the result:
1.) Find $P(X,Y)$ by marginalizing $Z$. This gives me $P(X,Y)=0.494$.
2.) Apply $0.494 * log_{2} \frac{1}{0.494}$. This gives me $U(X,Y) = 0.5026$.
3.) Then $U(Y|X)=U(X,Y)-U(X)=(-4973959)$.

Previously, I calculated $U(Y|X)$, as followed:
1.) Calculate $P(X=t) * U(Y|X=t) = 0.5*0.8400385= 0.42002$.
2.) Calculate $P(X=f) * U(Y|X=f) = 0.5*0.8486344= 0.42432$.
3.) Then $U(Y|X)=0.84434$.
4.) Finally, $MI(X,Y) = U(Y) - U(Y|X) = 0.9999538 - 0.84434 = 0.15562$, which half of the correct result.

Thanks so much.